# pass functions with different number of parameters to another function C++

Tags: c++, function-parameter

Imagine a function `func1` parameters of which are a function `f` and its arguments. Let there be two functions `func2` and `func3` which are supposed to be passed to `func1` with the following definitions:

```
bool func2(int a, int b, float c){
    // does something with arguments and returns the boolean result
}

bool func3(int a, int b, float c, float d){
    // does something with arguments and returns the boolean result
}
```

I wonder how should I define `func1` so that it can be compatible with both of these functions. Of course there is a turnaround and that is to pass a dummy parameter to `func2` but this is not a good solution. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712212/c-pass-arbitrary-number-of-arguments-to-another-function) but it did not seem to be a compatible solution. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

This function is a C++ template which is meant to be equivalent to a python function like:

```
def func1(f, int a, int b, *args):
    if f(a, b, *args):
        # does something
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719911/how-do-we-pass-an-arbitrary-function-to-another-function But this smells. Why do you need this?

Comment: @dyukha The point is I have to write some templates in C++ for some python function which handles this issue. in python, you can use a `*args` parameter for variable number of arguments to be passed to the function `f` in `func1` and I need an equivalent definition in C++.

Comment: I believe that you have [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and should edit your question and ask what you really want to do (namely, call python functions with variable number of parameters). First, your use-case probably eliminates any template-based solution (since they are compile-time entities). Second, this problem is probably very standard, and people would quickly answer it.

Comment: @dyukha maybe this edit solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variadic templates can help you. The simplest version:

```
template<class Fn, typename... Ts>
void func1(Fn fn, int a, int b, Ts... args) {
    if (fn(a, b, args...))
        ...
}

func1(func2, 1, 2, 3);
func1(func3, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a more readable code even if increases the number of lines one need to write.

Signature of `func2` and `func3` looks more of less similar. Hence you can make the `func2` accept another default parameter like below

```
bool func2(int a, int b, float c, float d = 0){
    // does something with arguments and returns the boolean result
}

bool func3(int a, int b, float c, float d){
    // does something with arguments and returns the boolean result
}
```

Now declare a function pointer and pass it to `func1`

```
bool (*fp) (int a, int b, float c, float d);

void func1(fp *fp1);
```

Please note that C++ doesn't really like function pointers

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a variadic template. Something like this should be fine (on mobile so may be syntax errors).

```
template<typename TCallback, typename TArgs...>
void Func1(TCallback Evt, TArgs... Args)
{
    Evt(Args...);
}

void Func2(int Arg1, int Arg2) { }

Func1(Func2, 10, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain but I believe you should be creating a templatized function. Something like this.

```
template<typename T>
void func1 (T x, T y) {
    //code
}
```

Theoretically you should be able to substitute x and y with the bool from your function or whatever other values. Essentially you're creating your own custom type.

I've linked a reference below. Hope this helps.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template